# Creating a table with sorting and filtering options

Tags: angular

I want to create a table with sorting and filtering options. I used 3 component to implement the table:
App.component.ts which include the original data and a function that filter that original data according to the searchText in filter.component.html. Then the filtered data should be sent to table.component.ts and displayed in a table on localhost:4200/.

My code did not work. In fact, the data is not displayed in the table. Can anyone please help me to find the problem? this in my code in plunker: 
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/9jepFqtDxJrDUdLo?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Plunker but it doesn't look like any of the usual Angular framework is there. I don't even see a function that actually bootstraps the application. You're also missing two of the packages you referenced in app.module.ts (angular-datatables and ngx-order-pipe), which seem pretty important to your application.

Finally, you've made the `listToDisplay` variable be a function instead of an array, which won't work as an input for `*ngFor`. Instead, turn it into a getter:

```
get listToDisplay() {
    // ...code here
}
```

Full example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o3ir1q).